# openlayers using without npm - beginner tutorial

Tags: openlayers

I've tried to include an openlayer-map on my page, but failed often, mainly because I don't have access to server(console) to do some fancy npm-stuff.
Then I tried to add build libraries from https://openlayers.org/download/ .
I then tried to add files from https://openlayers.org/doc/quickstart.html , main.js, index.html and style.css and all I get is a javascript-error:

TypeError: relative modulspecifier must start with "./", "../" or "/"

It will also fail with

@import "node_modules/ol/ol.css";

because there is no path "node_modules", nor do I know where to get.

The only valid examples I can find are dealing with libraries older than 8 years.

At the end, I want to show a (worldwide) map with many markers on it. That's it.

Am I looking at the wrong examples or is it not easy to implement?
Can someone please give some hint/link/example?

Regards
Jens

Comment: see this [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68227661/how-to-use-openlayers-6-5-examples/68228033#68228033) post

Comment: just change the paths to e.g. './node_modules/ol/ol.css';

Answer (score 1):

Version 4.6.5 examples are less than 5 years old https://openlayers.org/en/v4.6.5/examples/  Many will work with the latest version by updating the library paths in the header and explicitly sizing the map div

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.1.0/ol/ol.css" />
<style>
  .map {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/openlayers/openlayers.github.io@main/dist/en/v7.1.0/ol/dist/ol.js"></script>
```

or use the code from the latest examples and replace imported names with the full build syntax where `/` in import paths becomes `.`.